# Arabic language fonts not working in WPS writer - Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I've finally found a replacement for MS word in Linux Mint, but I'm having problems using WPS writer.
When I type in Arabic (in WPS writer only, [excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VF6j.gif) and [presentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eodhc.gif) work fine) [the fonts wont change if I change them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPrlZ.gif), I've tried to change language but all I find is *[English USA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL8mG.png)*.
Would be great if I can solve this, thanks allot!

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that WPS application only has one font for Arabic installed. (or none, did you just copy and paste the Arabic text into WPS writer from another application or did you type it) In the latter case, WPS writer may be missing the international font package entirely.

Although, you did state you are able to find more than one available font for
the Arabic language in WPS excel and presentation?
I find this odd. I would assume WPS has a single language font package that is used by all WPS writer, excel, but I suppose it could be separate.

Example:
a language font package 'arabic-writer', 'arabic-excel, etc.

In any case, all you should have to do is install additional Arabic fonts for WPS writer.

Methods of doing this in Linux mint;

1. Graphical - [Synaptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_(software))
2. Command line - apt-get

An alternative solution you might consider is using [libreoffice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice) instead of WPS. It can edit MS word files.

Comment: Thanks allot @labcomputing for answering, so what do you mean by "_installing additional Arabic fonts_"? Because WPS uses installed fonts on your system, and I've got a **ton** of those!
Also I don't use LibreOffice because I find the user interface and stability much better in WPS office.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to consider using [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/document), [Slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation), [Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets).
It can totally cover all your needs.

Comment: But they don't work offline, unless you use Chrome, which is not the case with me.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing an arabic font like this in this directory /usr/share/font/wps-office [Arabic Font](https://arbfonts.com//wp-content/fonts/new-arabic-fonts//Behdad-Regular-3.ttf)